# regular expression to find in wpf xaml

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I want to find in visual studio (C#) in WPF all the occurrences of the pattern:

Content="

and after the " I want to find only the occurrences that do not continue with {

for example:

I **want** to find: Content="This is a button"

I **do not** want to find: Content="{StaticResource ThisIsAButton}"

I am very bad at regular expression.

Any Idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Try this regex: `/"[^{]*"/`

Comment: Testing some expressions out and researching online is a prime way to get better at regex. I always find this helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
Found the answer using the idea of bejado.

Content="([^{]*)"

Comment: I used regex101.com to experiment, by the way. Great way to test.